# What are the valid regular expression formats for the nonProxyHosts property in Java?

Tags: java, regex, proxy

When using the `proxyHost`, `proxyPort` and `nonProxyHosts` properties in Java to modify a `URL` connection, what are the valid uses of wildcards in the `nonProxyHosts` property?  Could I do any or all of the following?

1. explicit server name: `nonProxyHosts=server.company.com`
2. any server in subdomain: `nonProxyHosts=*.local.company.com`
3. specific server by IP address: `nonProxyHosts=192.168.101.110`
4. any server in subnet: `nonProxyHosts=192.168.101.*`
5. any server in subnet: `nonProxyHosts=192.168.101/23`

Are there other types of patterns?

Thanks!

Comment: I think by "regular expression", you mean "wildcard"? These examples don't look like [RegEx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Syntax) at all to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the interpretation of the property value is that it defines a pool of regular expressions. If the host matches any expression in the pool (both the host and expressions are forced to lower-case), then no proxy is used.

Edit:
Or not quite. It looks like `sun.misc.RegexpPool` only handles strings that either begin or end with "*". So I guess this really does boil down to just prefix and suffix wildcards...

Edit2:
A quick way to test is to use:

```
ProxySelector.getDefault().select(URI.create("...myURI..."));
```

Which will return `List<Proxy>`. The default proxy selector is `sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector`, but it can be overridden.

Comment: The quick way (Edit2) works like a charm. You have just test the type of proxy(s) returned into the list

Answer (score 8):

Check out the OpenJDK source for `sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector` and `sun.misc.Regexp` classes. The `nonProxyHosts` System property gets processed there for the Sun JVM. The Regexp class was written by the Java man himself, James Gosling, according to the `@author` javadoc comment. All it does is match `*` regular expressions, anywhere in a string (start, middle and end). So, you can do partial hostnames as well as partial IP addresses, such as `host12*` or `10.*` to match all hostnames starting with `host12` or all IPs starting with `10.`. Also, `DefaultProxySelector` detects `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` in proxied URLs and automatically excludes them. So you don't need to add those to your `nonProxyHosts` as far as the Sun JVM is concerned.

Now, in Weblogic it seems they have their own `weblogic.net` classes that operate with the same Sun System net properties, but not always the same way. I don't have the Weblogic source handy, but my point is, it's not only the Sun JDK that uses these properties. YMMV with different proxy implementations out there due to bugs or different semantics or interpretations of the Sun behavior and docs.

The OpenJDK source version I referenced was from openjdk-6 at http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/.

Comment: Great code dissection. This pretty much answer the question and also my curiosity.

Answer (score 5):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/net/properties.html says:

> http.nonProxyHosts indicates the hosts which should be connected too directly and not
>   through the proxy server. The value can be a list of hosts, each seperated by a |, and
>   **in addition a wildcard character (*) can be used for matching**. For example:
>
> -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="*.foo.com|localhost".

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I'm trying to get a definition of.  Can I use wildcards in IP addresses?  Can I use CIDR notation?  Thanks!

Comment: I interpret that as that CIDR isn't possible but that you can use wildcards in IPs (when something is being requested by IP) and hostnames (when something is being requested by hostname).

Comment: Link gives 404 in 2021